# Obtain data from Friday, Saturday and Sunday if today is Monday SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am looking to obtain all data in a table from yesterday in SQL Oracle.

This is simply enough using the WHERE clause, i.e,

```
SELECT *
FROM My_Data
WHERE TO_DATE(My_Data.Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
```

However if I now need to add more logic where if the day of the query is a Monday (SYSDATE) then obtain data between Friday and Sunday.

Using a between statement is no issue, I'm just not sure if I can include in a where statement given I'm unable to use case statement here.

Thanks

Comment: You do not need a `case` **expression**. Use `OR` in a `where` clause instead of `CASE`, it's clear in reading and understanding: `where ("Date" >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 and "Date" < trunc(sysdate)) or (to_char("Date", 'DY', 'NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') = 'MON' and "Date" >= trunc(sysdate) - 3 and "Date" < trunc(sysdate))`. Also do not use `to_date` on dates, use `trunc` instead, and do not use keywords as a column names as they always require quoted identifiers and then become case-sensitive

Comment: Hi astentx, I will take a look at this and perhaps update if this is best practice as opposed to using a case statement. Also why wouldnt you use To_Date on a date column?

Comment: What is a point of casting date to a date? This particular case relies on implicit type casts: if you check the documentation of [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118): *TO_DATE **converts char** to a value of DATE data type.* So it performs date -> char -> date conversion, which uses `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting (which doesn't contain hours, minutes and seconds by default). If you, for some reason, change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and add hours etc to format picture, this trick will not work anymore.

Comment: See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y7LptaA8)

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes sense. Thanks for sending the fiddle across to illustrate what you are saying. Again I appreciate you taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    My_Data
WHERE
    TO_DATE(My_Data.Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        Between Case When To_Char(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'MON' Then TRUNC(SYSDATE)-3 ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 END 
        And TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
```

You can use the Case expression in Where clause. Regards...

Comment: Hi d r this is perfect. Thank you for answering so quickly too. Good to know you can use a case in a where statement

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a date (and if it is a string then don't store dates as strings).

So you are not dependent on the date language session parameter, you can compare the date to the start of the ISO week (which is independent of language) and you can compare on a date range so that Oracle can use an index on your date column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   My_Data
WHERE  "DATE" <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    "DATE" >= CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                 WHEN 0 -- Monday
                 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3
                 ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
                 END;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   My_Data
WHERE  "DATE" <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    (  ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') = 0 AND "DATE" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3 )
       OR "DATE" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
       );
```

Comment: Hi MT0, I will take a look at your code and see if this works as well. I assume this would run faster given Oracle is able to index?